# Firebase authentication in desktop application

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, flutter-web, flutter-desktop

After the announcement of Flutter v2.10, I start working on my desktop application and I want to implement firebase authentication but unfortunately, firebase_auth packages don't support desktop till now so is there any way to authenticate the user with firebase in a desktop application.

Since we have desktop support so I planning to authenticate on the web and after authentication redirect again on the desktop application but I don't know how this works anyone has any idea about this or any other way?

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!
https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a platform for which no Firebase Authentication SDK is available, you can call its [REST APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth) instead. This can be done from any platform that can call HTTP endpoints, including Flutter.

Comment: Ok, thanks I surely check that.